# Can't access 3rd party API, code works on local server but not on wordpress

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, html, rest-api

I've been working on a project and I just cant pull the data from this API.
I'm developing a plugin that's supposed to pull data from an API and then use that data.
I developed this project offline and after it was working I started developing inside the WordPress plugin space.

but for some reason i'm not getting any data.

---

Following is my request.

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'precious_metals' );
function precious_metals (  ) {  
$content = file_get_contents("A WORKING API"); //Doing this for a client so hiding the API to be safe ;)

$result  = json_decode($content);
}
```

---

Following is my display(which is working offline).
The table headings do display but no data 
is being pulled from the API.

```
<H4>New data fetched</H4>
    <table border = solid 1px>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Type</b></td>
            <td><b>$value</b></td>
        </tr>
    <?php foreach($result as $key=>$value): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $key; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $value; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you `print_r($content)` to see what response you are getting back from the working API??

Comment: Yes i can and its completely empty.

Comment: @ChristopherJones on my local server i get the full table back displayed with all the data i need, its just in wordpress the $content is empty

Answer (score 0):

Can you drop this in and let us know what `$content` looks like?

```
<?php
  $c = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "A WORKING API");
  $content = curl_exec($c);
  curl_close($c);

  echo '<pre>';
  print_r($content);
  echo '</pre>';
```

I am curious if this is a WordPress issue or just a CORS issue with the call being made from a different host.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use `file_get_contents` for remote request. The function that you should be looking at is `wp_remote_get` or `wp_remote_post` depending on what data you want to send to the api before receiving a response. In any case your code should be somewhat similar to:

```
$request  = wp_remote_get( 'http://example.com' );
$response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );
if (200 !== wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response ))
    wp_send_json_error( $response );
wp_send_json_success( $response );
```

Note that `wp_send_json_success/_error` functions are wrappers for `wp_send_json()`, which includes `wp_die()` at the end. So you don't have to call `wp_die()` after `wp_send_json_` functions.

Also, most of time remote APIs are sending **200 status code** in general unless the api server fails to interpret your input variables in API call. So you'll still have to manually verify the result before using it.